# Solidity: What is a state variable not available in my test?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix

I'm using Remix and have something like this...

```
contract EthText {
  address payable public owner;
  ...
  constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
```

Where I'm setting the owner to deployer.
And when I publish I have an owner button..
[image]

Which I can click and get the Contracts address.

But, when I write a test for this, the 'owner' is not working.

```
import "remix_tests.sol"; // this import is automatically injected by Remix.
import "remix_accounts.sol";
import "../EthText.sol";


contract ContractTest {
    EthText testContract;
    address acc0;
    address acc1;
    
    function beforeEach() public {
        testContract = new EthText();
        acc0 = TestsAccounts.getAccount(0); 
        acc1 = TestsAccounts.getAccount(1);
    }
    
    function depoyerIsOwner() public {
        Assert.equal(testContract.owner, address(acc0), '');
    }
}
```

So my contract has the interface available as a button, but not for testing. And, also — I'm just guessing that this is the cause of the test failure given the cryptic test-failure message:

`browser/tests/EthText_test.sol:24:9: TypeError: Member "equal" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(library Assert). Assert.equal(testContract.owner, address(acc0), ''); ^----------^`

So why does this not work?

Is the answer to explicitly create a getter function to return the owner variable? If so, why is it available as a button?

Thank! I'm pretty new to Solidity, so ‍♂️

Comment: TypeError: Member "equal" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(library Assert). This means you're importing that assert library twice, or their are 2 implementations of the equal function on an assert object.  Does EthText.sol also import assert?

Comment: Also, are you sure you get the contracts address? It seems you're pretty clearly setting it to `msg.sender`